# 'JSONKit.h' not found when I run 'Test' of my Project in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, cocoapods

I used CocoaPods to add JSONKit to project.

Now I want to create a unit test of a function in my project which uses JSONKit function.

When I hit ⌘U to run the test, I got this error message:

[image]

I am positive the project can compile can run without problem when I hit ⌘R ('Run')

What is the reason for the error message? How can I fix it?

I am using XCode 5.0.2

Comment: Is that header file in a different directory? You might have to add the folder that contains the header in your "Header Search Paths" section of Build Settings for your QuestionsTests target (change to this target in the drop-down in the upper-left corner of the project settings screen).

Comment: No. As mentioned in the question, the main app can be compiled and run with no problem. This header issue only happens when I try to run 'Test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a Pod file setup problem.

I need to add the following as the first line in my podifle.

```
link_with ['Questions', 'QuestionsTests']
```

Then rerun `pod install` and reopen workspace in xcode.